# Best workaround for monitoring clicks on dynamic links within Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What is the best *in-Journey-Builder* workaround you have when you want to retarget clicks on dynamic links in mails in Journey Builder?
I'd use queries myself, but I'd really like to know of any alternative solutions for less experienced marketeers working in Journey Builder only.
It's all related to [this](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKNqQAM), would offer a ton of dynamics to the use of Journey Builder and would be incredibly valuable to be able to handle!
THANK YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no best workaround because this is a workaround, not an OOTB functionality that is usually suitable for the bigger number of use-cases. So let's hope one day, the [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKNqQAM) would be finally released.

1. There is already a "default" workaround, which is explained in [Trailhead's module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/engagement-splits-in-journey-builder-using-ampscript).

   - It considers you would need to create a Decision Split that would serve the purpose of the Engagement Split. This Decision Split would check the values of the contact's clicks within the separate Data Extension, which will be populated via Automation Studio by querying Data Views, and then send contacts to designated paths.
2. Then, there is also a possibility to track clicks by creating buffer CloudPage that would receive parameters, where one of them would tell to which actuall page customer should be redirected. But before redirection, you would have [InsertData](https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/) AMPscript function that would populate designated Data Extension with identifying information of the customer and the clicked link that were passed via URL parameters. This method is usually used to track SMS yet could be adapted to be used with emails.

P.S. would not definitely say it is the only available approach though.